# GitHub pages 404ing for .txt files but not any other files

Tags: github, github-pages, web-hosting

It's in the title.

I've been trying to get text file app-ads.txt hosted at the root directory of my site

When I go to mysite.com/index.html it works fine, but when I go to any .txt file (e.g. mysite.com/app-ads.txt or any other file like mysite.com/test.txt) it is a 404.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After waiting an hour, the text files are now available at their respective addresses.

If you're having this issue, wait an hour or two for changes to propagate before thinking "something is broken".

Comment: It is usually faster than an hour, but yep, waiting a bit usually does the trick.